# How to iterate thorugh JArray items in list

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, json.net

This is my json data:

```
{
    "date": "2016-08-26",
    "time_of_day": "14:19",
    "request_time": "2016-08-26T14:19:59+01:00",
    "station_name": "Derby",
    "station_code": "DBY",
    "departures": {
      "all": [
        {   
           "service": "22152000",
        },
        {
           "service": "22150000",
        },
        {
           "service": "22180008",
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to put each one of these service variables from the json above into a list. Afer this I then want to call each one of these the service variables individually wihtin a api link. This is my C# code:

```
JArray items = new JArray();
items.Add(service["service"]);
int serviceLength = items.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    string moreJson = get_web_content("http://transportapi.com/v3/uk/train/service/" + items[i] + "/" + date + "/" + hours + ":" + minutes + "/timetable.json?" + appID + "/" + appKey);

    dynamic schedluedContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(moreJson);
    JArray items2 = new JArray();

    foreach (JObject stops in schedluedContent.stops)
    {

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Station Code"] = stops["station_code"];
        dr["Station Name"] = stops["station_name"];
        dr["Aimed Arrival Time"] = stops["aimed_arrival_time"];

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        GridViewTrainTimes.DataSource = dt;
        GridViewTrainTimes.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can do it easily if you convert your json to a model  http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: I have no idea where to begin with that but I will look into it thank you!

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't seem to match up with the data. There is no mention of `aimed_arrival_time` or `stop` in your source json. Should `stops` be departures?

Comment: @Ceilingfish - I reckon the JSON shown represents a single entry in a larger json object that looks like `{ "stops": [ { ... the object in the question ...} ] }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SelectTokens()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) to find all service values.  `SelectTokens()` supports querying of multiple properties nested deep inside JSON objects with wildcards and/or filters using the [JSONPath syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

```
var services = stops
    .SelectTokens("departures.all[*].service")
    .Select(t => (string)t)
    .ToList();
```

Here `[*]` is the wildcard operator returning all entries in the `departures.all[]` array.

For a full description of JSONPath see [here](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f3racs).